# “Every time no one’s around” or "every time when no one’s around"

Tags: grammar

> I couldn’t help but stare at him **every time when** no one’s around

Or

> I couldn’t help but stare at him **every time** no one’s around

Which is correct?

Comment: Neither is correct. "No one's" in both cases should instead be "no one was." If you were to correct that both would be correct, but the second one would be the best because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The construction **every time when...** is not idiomatic. No examples of it can be found on Google Books Ngram Viewer.

**Every time** can either be followed by **that** or by the clause that follows without **that**. For example:

> Every time that he comes here, he brings flowers

or

> Every time he comes here, he brings flowers.

The construction **no one's** is likely to be understood as **no one is** although it might possibly be interpreted in some contexts as **no one was** or **no one has**.

So you need to phrase your sentences either in the present tense as:

> I can't help but stare at him every time (that) no one's [*is*] around.

or, in the past tense as:

> I couldn't help but stare at him every time (that) no one was around.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everry+time+when%2Cevery+time+tha

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct.

The second form is a bit better, because it is shorter.

The meaning of both is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

These both sound wrong; "no one's" is a contraction for "no one is", but we would want "no one was" there, instead.

That being said, the second one is better because the "when" is redundant - we already have said "time", so saying "when" is repeating ourselves a bit.

Also I would prefer "any" to "every", but the differences are subtle.  Also, "anytime *we were alone*" is worth considering.